# What is the current status of Mir / XMir?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mir

I am totally unclear about the status of Mir as of today.

Especially, I was waiting for an enhancement on XMir to support color profiles, but a recent comment on bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmir/+bug/1211063 reads:

> XMir is not a thing any more. But certainly we would like colour
>   profiles for Unity8 eventually.

So, what is the current state of Mir / Xmir, etc... This is especially interesting as I'm waiting for the first Ubuntu Phone to launch (MX4 probably?) and I'm lost regarding the global direction the platform is going to.

EDIT: this might be somehow related https://plus.google.com/109365858706205035322/posts/Ad5rMy2f2ZG , or not... I'm still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn and follow MIR development through the official websites:

1 - http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/

Submit to the developers mailing list to receive constant updates:

2 - https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/mir-devel

Finally see the status of MIR here:

3 - https://code.launchpad.net/~mir-team

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably choose this answer if no other comes, but really, reading those sources did not enlighten me...

Comment: Those links give you the current state of MIR developing. There's not much to it. It looks like MIR is under developing at a slow pace.

Comment: That's my feeling, but Mir is supposed to be one of the key components of Ubuntu's convergence strategy. Also, other distributions (be it desktop or phone like Sailfish) are using wayland. Is the Mir strategy still ongoing, or is Ubuntu slowly changing its mind on that ?

Comment: That only developers can say. My guess is that MIR will go on and will be the default X server for all Ubuntu platforms. It simply is on slowly developing.